# Creating a regex with special characters in Web Harvest

Tags: xml, regex, webharvest

I am using web harvest (http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/), the open source web scraping tool.

The regex I am trying to use has "<", ">" characters (because I am trying to strip out all HTML tags that come in). This causes a problem because the content of the elements  must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

I need to somehow escape the regex, but can't figure out how.

Any ideas?

Comment: HTML parsing is a solved problem. Consider do you actually need to reinvent a solution using a regex. A mandatory SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

To make the regular expression well-formed XML. Try replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`. Similarly if you have an `&` in your regular expression you will need to replace that with `&amp;`.

Also I'd suggest you use an HTML parser instead of a regular expression for this task.